# Sort csv columns in alphabetical order and print out (JAVA)

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, bufferedreader, columnsorting

```
List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(str));
          Stream lines = r.lines().skip(1);

          lines.forEachOrdered(
              line -> {
               line= ((String) line).replace("\"", "");
                 ret.add((String) line);
```

The above code prints out all the data from csv file and looks something like this

```
Employee, id,   address, 
Jon,     2034,  4 main av,
```

How can I get it to print out the columns in alphabetical order?
so it should look like this

```
address,     employee, id,
4 main av,   Jon,      2034,
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest introducing some new class and overriding it's `toString` method and specify the order to be printed there and handle like below
This should work

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<String> ret;
        File file = new File("/Users/A.csv");
        InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(targetStream));
        ret = r.lines().skip(1).map(line -> new Person(line).toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(ret);
    }

    static class Person {
        private String id;
        private String employee;
        private String address;

        public Person(String line) {
            String[] lineParts = line.replace("\"", "").split(",");
            this.employee = lineParts[0];
            this.id = lineParts[1];
            this.address = lineParts[2];
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.join(",", this.address, this.employee, this.id);
        }
    }
}

static class Person {
    private String id;
    private String employee;
    private String address;

    public Person(String line) {
        String[] lineParts = line.replace("\"", "").split(",");
        this.employee = lineParts[0];
        this.id = lineParts[1];
        this.address = lineParts[2];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.join(",", this.address, this.employee, this.id);
    }
}
```